# how remove background in new version of runtime in google swiffy

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

I use google swiffy for convert my swf file to html5.
But now google is upgraded runtime to v 5.2 and can't use transparent background.
Before i use runtime v 4.9 of google swiffy html5 from swf file and in google code i remove this from my javascript file for use transparenty background:

```
"backgroundColor":-1,
```

But now runtime is upgraded to v5.2 and i can`t remove background color from swiffy file

https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#div *:first-child {
      background-color: transparent !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution work perfectly with flash cs5 -> swiffy v5.3!

```
#swiffycontainer rect {
    background: none !important;
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand this answer: I'm running Swiffy 5.2.0 and this didn't work at the very beginning since the internal generated code is different in my case, it looks like this:

```
<div id="my-container">
    <!-- Begins Swiffy generated code -->
    <div style="position: relative; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(102, 121, 14); cursor: default; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
        <svg color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" style="fill-rule: evenodd; pointer-events: none; -webkit-user-select: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <!-- svg contents here -->
        </svg>
    <!-- Ends Swiffy generated code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note that my-container is the container that I assigned in the stage constructor, not generated by Swiffy.*

**Just check for the generated code and adjust css selector as necessary**, the original idea still remains the same:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #my-container div {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Roger's solution worked perfectly for me: I'm using Swiffy in a Wordpress Environment, so here's what I did:

1) Add the Swiffy-generated   code into the header.php file (actually header-home.php so I could call it for only one page).

2) Before the Swiffy , add Roger's code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#swiffycontainer div {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
</style>
```

3) Place the Swiffy-generated  code that came AFTER the  (before the close of the  tag) into the footer.php file (again, footer-home.php in my case).

4) Put the Swiffy container ('id="swiffycontainer"' by default) Div on the WordPress page.

Tah-Dah! I would have simply voted Roger up, but I don't have the rep to do so. Plus I thought my WordPress situation might help others.

Answer (score 0):

GOOGLE HAVE THE ANSWER:

https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/faq.html

How can I make the background transparent?

If you need to make the background transparent, as done by the wmode="transparent" attribute, you can insert the following code snippet in the Swiffy output, just before the call to stage.start():

stage.setBackground(null);

You can also replace the null with any valid CSS color specification string to override the background color from the one defined in the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and searching in the web, and try everything, also described in this post, finally I've find the solution!!

When you export and .swf in flash CS6 to html5 (canvas), open the .html file exported in a html editor and change the background-color attribute to #transparent"

Example:

```
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#transparent">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="300" style="background-color:#transparent"></canvas>
</body>
```

Well, it works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the "setBackground" method to null after starting up the stage. Like so,

```
stage.start();
stage.setBackground(null);
```